# Cypress - How to select the sub menu from the menu with no class or id?

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom, cypress

Below is the html that I am working on:
`

```
<li xpath="1">
                <a href="#" onclick="clearNewTabInvoiceDetails()" class="fruit">Fruits<span class="menu-arrow"></span></a>
                <ul class="sub-menu">
                 <li>
                <a href="/apple/Index" onclick="clearNewTabInvoiceDetails()" class="apple">
                    Apples
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="/mango/Index" onclick="clearNewTabInvoiceDetails()" class="mango">
                    Mangoes
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="/banana/Index" onclick="clearNewTabInvoiceDetails()" class="banana">
                    Pineapples
                </a>
            </li>
            </li>

<li xpath="1">
                <a href="#" onclick="clearNewTabInvoiceDetails()" class="drink">Drinks<span class="menu-arrow"></span></a>
                <ul class="sub-menu">
                 <li>
                <a href="/coke/Index" onclick="clearNewTabInvoiceDetails()" class="coke">
                    Coke
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="/fanta/Index" onclick="clearNewTabInvoiceDetails()" class="fanta">
                    Fanta
                </a>
            </li>
          </ul>
```

There are two menus with the same sub menu class which is . I want to select only one sub menu from ul which is id="main-nav. I want only the sub menus of fruits. I tried #main-nav li::nth-child(1) but, it's not working.
There are two () I want to mark all the sub-menus of the first 
[Image of sub menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5OsO5.png)

[Please click here for more detail](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b2mZa.png)

`

Comment: Can you please post the HTML instead of the text output, use ctrl+K for code snippeting

Comment: Try `#main-nav li:nth-of-type(1)`

Comment: And please post also what have you tried and where you are stucked

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example it will help you put your code into the question in such a way that we can see its structure and so help you.

Comment: Is this a related to cypress?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the adjacent sibling selector `+` in CSS to select an element of class `sub-menu` immediately preceded by an element with class `fruit`:

```css
.fruit+.sub-menu {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<li xpath="1">
  <a href="#" onclick="clearNewTabInvoiceDetails()" class="fruit">Fruits<span class="menu-arrow"></span></a>
  <ul class="sub-menu">
    <li>
      <a href="/apple/Index" onclick="clearNewTabInvoiceDetails()" class="apple">
                    Apples
                </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="/mango/Index" onclick="clearNewTabInvoiceDetails()" class="mango">
                    Mangoes
                </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="/banana/Index" onclick="clearNewTabInvoiceDetails()" class="banana">
                    Pineapples
                </a>
    </li>
  </ul>

  <li xpath="1">
    <a href="#" onclick="clearNewTabInvoiceDetails()" class="drink">Drinks<span class="menu-arrow"></span></a>
    <ul class="sub-menu">
      <li>
        <a href="/coke/Index" onclick="clearNewTabInvoiceDetails()" class="coke">
                    Coke
                </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="/fanta/Index" onclick="clearNewTabInvoiceDetails()" class="fanta">
                    Fanta
                </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
```